# Simple Syntax Question (tuple conversion)

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, data-conversion

I'm currently researching different ways to combine, organize and manipulate data for different purposes.

Just today I found this zip() / iter() technique of creating a LIST containing TUPLES while also being able to specify how many elements are in each TUPLE. However, I'm unable to fully understand part of the syntax.

Here is the code:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

converted = [x for x in zip(*[iter(mylist)]*2)]

print(converted)
```

This is the output (which is what I want):

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

What I'm trying to grasp is the first asterisk. I understand that it's most likely in relation to the '*2' telling the 'iter' or 'zip' function how many elements each tuple should contain, however, I'm trying to grasp the need for it's placement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, if you know of another technique to accomplish this and feel like sharing, I'd greatly appreciate learning from you.

Thanks again in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `iter(mylist)` makes an iterator object for the list, then it's put into a list `[iter(mylist)]` which is multiplied by 2 basically making a list that contains two references to the same iterator object: `[iter(mylist)]*2` -> `[<list_iterator object at 0x7f8fbc1ac610>, <list_iterator object at 0x7f8fbc1ac610>]`

The first asterisk unpacks the list as arguments into the zip() function.
To make it easier to understand as I'm not very good at explaining things, this code does the same as yours:

```py
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

iterators = [iter(mylist)] * 2
converted = [x for x in zip(*iterators)]

print(converted)
```

So it makes an iterator, then it makes a list that contains two references to the same iterator object by multiplying it by 2.
And then it unpacks the list to be used as arguments for the `zip()` function

I hope this cleared it up at least a little for you as I'm not very good at explaining.

Comment: I think you explained as well as possible when trying to explain something like this. I understand it isn't easy. This is helps me! Thanks for taking time to answer this post.

Comment: So essentially, what's happening is this:

The ' *2 ' is creating two different iterable objects...
While the '*' is consolidating those lists using the for loop.

Right?

Comment: This is basically tuple unpacking, you can unpack lists like tuples as well.

Comment: For the '2', what Python is doing is the following: `[iter(mylist)]*2`. It will first create the iterator object and the list, then the list is multiplied by 2 creating a new list with the SAME iterator but two times in the list.

Comment: Got it. I still enjoy understanding the underpinning madness going on. Thanks alot

Comment: The \* will *unpack* the resulting list to be used as arguments for zip(). Think of it like this: `args = [2, 3]; myfunc(*args)` would be the same as `myfunc(2, 3)`. That's what the \* is doing

Comment: Ah, that helps. So this is more like "tuple packing" I guess